# Copying text from raw file to clipboard

Tags: java, android, textview, clipboard

I have a raw file with content:

```
Ah, dearest Jesus, holy Child,
make Thee a bed, soft, undefiled
within my heart, that it may be
a quiet chamber kept for Thee.

My heart for very joy doth leap,
My lips no more can silence keep;
I, too, must sing with joyful tongue
That sweetest ancient cradle song.

Glory to God in highest Heaven,
Who unto man His Son hath given;
While angels sing with tender mirth,
a glad new year to all the earth.
Amen.
```

When I use the setText method of TextView, it shows up fine but when I copy the above text to clipboard by using the following code, the new line characters are missing. How to fix it.

```
((ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE))
                        .setText(tv.getText());
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this seems to be a repeated complaint with certain versions of Android, and I haven't found a simple solution to it.

That being said, I see two options.  The first is to try replacing the new line characters with \n, the Android character for hard return.  That might solve your problem.

If it doesn't, you may just want to put a space before each hard return so that it doesn't run the words together when copied.  Hope you're able to get it figured out!

Comment: Got it working. Here is my code: String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");      ((ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE)).setText(tv.getText().replace(newLine, " "));